# Histogram meets bubble chart: what kind of chart is this?

Tags: data-visualization, histogram

I really like this histogram-come-bubble chart thing. It appears to have some force/physics elements.

Does it have a name? Can anyone speculate how I might go about making one?
https://pudding.cool/2017/07/comics/

[image: The chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "beeswarm plot": the $x$ coordinate represents the percentage of female members per team, and dots are jittered around until all are visible. Note that jittering happens in both dimensions. (An actual $x$ axis would be useful.) The colors indicate whether the team is less than 50% female (gray) or more than 50% (red).

You can create this kind of plot with the [`beeswarm` package for R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/beeswarm/index.html). I don't have the underlying data, but here is an example with some random data:

```
library(beeswarm)

?beeswarm
set.seed(1)
ratios <- runif(2862)

beeswarm(x=ratios,horizontal=TRUE,pch=19,cex=0.6,
  pwcol=c("black","red")[(ratios>0.5)+1])
```

[image: beeswarm]

To get something like your plot, you'd add some more `text()`, `lines()` and potentially `arrows()` commands.